# Java: Writing to socket with DataOutputStream slows down, then stops

Tags: java, sockets, buffer, send

```
while (true) {
    loc = getLocationOnScreen();

    out.writeLong((long)loc.getX());
    out.writeLong((long)loc.getY());
    out.flush();

    i++;
    System.out.println(i);

}
```

This code will merrily go along for about 3 seconds, before it slows, then stops.

`i` ends at about `16491`, never to continue increasing. What's going on here?

Comment: Where is your stream ending?

Comment: @bmorris591 Not really sure what you mean. I'm quite new to Java sockets, and I'm only hacking out a simple project.

Comment: So you're writing to a socket? What's at the other end? Could the other end be not reading and a buffer filling up?

Comment: @bmorris591 The other end's Python, and I'm constantly reading from it.

Comment: How are you reading contantly? Where does the code block?

Comment: @jbnizet Basically, in a `While 1:` loop I'm reading 16 bytes each time.

Answer (score 1):

It is slowing down because , at the receiving end you might be doing long task using the value sent by you , before reading the next value. So the rate at which the other side is reading the data is smaller than the rate at which you are sending data to that. This keeps filling the receiving buffer at the other side and sending buffer at sender side. Eventually when both buffers are filled completely the transmission of data is halted.

Comment: But as long as I keep reading values, the `i` should increment, however slowly.

Comment: After the buffers are full , The receiver would firstly clear that full buffer , and also the send would firstly clear its sending buffer .Until sufficient buffer is available  TCP halts the transmission and thereafter The transmission again continues but very slowly ..

Comment: But it's not just going very slowly, it's not going at all.

Comment: I told you.. That after certain amount of time when both buffers are full then **TCP halts the transmission** . Keep your program running for long time , you would see value of `i` increase again but very slowly and again halt thereafter.